# How to link users in GCP/Firebase Identity Platform to IAM principal

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-oauth, google-identity

**Background**
We are building an app which authenticates end user using Firebase Authentication (backed by GCP Identity Platform). At the same time, we leverage some Google API of which permission is set based on IAM Role/Principal. That means the API call is valid only if the caller calls the API with a valid access token of authorized IAM Principal.

According to Doug in this post: [How to add Firebase auth user to GCP IAM access policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461337/how-to-add-firebase-auth-user-to-gcp-iam-access-policy) "IAM doesn't know anything about Firebase Authentication users."

**Already tried**: Add the Firebase user as an IAM Principal when it's created. It works only for the user signs in user Google account. Otherwise, IAM will throw error "Email addresses and domains must be associated with an active Google Account, Google Workspace account, or Cloud Identity account."

**Question**: Is there any recommended way to authorize Firebase user accessing Google API? Do I need to build a customized authorization layer in Firebase to keep track of who can access what. Then, use that as a guard to relay the requests to the underlying Google API only if the user is authorized by the authorization logic?

Comment: It might be better to use Cloud functions to make requests to the Google API and check if requesting user has access to it or no instead of adding users to IAM.